# DescribeImagesRequest filters

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services

The DescribeImagesRequest API gives me back a list of servers that our users cannot launch. In our case the users are restricted to 'micro' instance sizes, so cannot launch anything like "Windows with SQL Servers 2012" (which is only permitted for larger instance deployments). Is there a way to get the API to give back only instances that we can launch with our 'micro' restriction?

Comment: What do you mean by "give back only instances"? Are you asking for a list of **AMIs** that can be launched on a given **Instance Type**?

Comment: Yes, you've got the right idea. I only want the Amazon AMIs retrieved which will support the micro instance sizes.

Answer (score 0):

This information is not stored against AMIs, so it is **not available as a searchable field**.

The [AWS Marketplace](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/paid-amis.html#using-paid-amis-finding-paid-ami) does show which Instance Types are available for listings, so I suspect that this information *would* be available for Marketplace listings. However, Marketplace AMIs are different to normal AMIs, typically involving a cost.